# Can't login ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Today I tried logging in in ubuntu but when I enter my password it keeps going to a black screen with text and then it gets me back to the login screen. 
When I press ctrl + alt + F1 I can login in the console.
However when I start the console it says -bash: export: '/etc/profile' not a valid identifier.
Also, it says the .Xauthorization filesize is 0.
I have tried every solution I could find so far but nothig worked.

-Finn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When logged into the console, please provide output from:

```
grep -nH export /etc/profile
grep -nH export ~/.profile
grep -nH export ~/.bashrc
grep -nH export ~/.bash_profile
grep -nH export /etc/bash.bashrc
```

.

**Edit:**
Thanks for running the commands.

A problem appears on line 36 of /etc/profile:

```
/etc/profile:36:export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml source /etc/profile
```

Remove the text at the end of line 36:

> " source /etc/profile"

Well... **actually lines 35 and 36 are twins.  Just delete line 36.**

Does that solve all of your problems, or does a problem persist?

This should remove the "not a valid identifier" error.

Comment: grep -nH export /etc/profile =
`/etc/profile:33:export JAVA_HOME
/etc/profile:34:export PATH
/etc/profile:35:export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml
/etc/profile:36:export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml source /etc/profile`

grep -nH export ~/.profile =
`No output`

grep -nH export ~/.bashrc =
`No output`

grep -nH export ~/.bash_profile =
`grep: /home/finn/.bash_profile: No such file or directory`

grep -nH export /etc/bash.bashrc =
`No output`

Comment: @Finn, thanks for the grep-output.  See my edit: line 36 of /etc/profile has an extraneaous "source" command.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on how to install metasploit on ubuntu 12.04 and it said I had to type `sudo sh -c "echo export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/opt/metasploit-framework/database.yml >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile"` I'll try to remove line 36 however I don't know what command to use.

Comment: That tutorial should have had "source /etc/profile" on a second command line or at least have put a ; before "source".  Use vi to edit the file.  **Copy it first!**  Or use an editor you are familiar with.

Comment: Thank's for the help. just one last question, what should I copy and where?

Comment: `cp -p /etc/profile /etc/profile.20140226`  That gives you a backup from before you edit.